# Date format different in Actual file(CSV) and the excel file

Tags: excel, date-format

I have a csv file with a date and time field.Now if the CSV file is opened in textpad or notepad++ the time format is 24 hrs but if the same is opened using excel (2007) it is is 12 hr format. For example if it is 6/4/2012 15:00:00 in the csv file then it is 6/4/2012 3:00:00 PM

The format cell options is also not helpful.

I want the same format in excel.I think i am missing some internal settings

Answer (score 1):

Following would help you if you wish to format time in Excel

On the cell, right click and go to Format Cell
There will be a tab labeled Number (the first one)
select the appropriate Category from the list (Time, in yor case)
choose one of the formats listed. (one of the bottom two, at least in Office 2003)

If none of the formats matches what you want, select one that is close to what you want, then choose the Custom category. You can now edit the format however you choose using the format you chose to customize and the other pre-defined custom formats as a guide

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An other option is to import the csv into Excel from `Data > From Text` then go through the wizard and import the columns as text (on step 3 of the wizard) and then excel should not change the format